# Como tratar un campo date de un formulario html en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

El siguiente código es para crear un formulario de Consulta de WhatsApp sobre alojamiento temporario, pero me encuentro en un dilema con las fechas... no las reconoce Javascript, son 2, "desde" y "hasta", porque pasa esto?... que debería hacer para que dichas fechas se impriman en el whatsapp con el formato:

- Desde: dd/mm/aaaa
- Hasta: dd/mm/aaaa

Esta es la carga del formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el WhatsApp que obtengo:

---

Hola!, Consulta desde El Sitio Web

- Mi nombre: Ricardo
- Propiedad: Villa Bonita 1
- Desde:
- Hasta:
- Para: 4 personas.
- Mensaje: Consulto por disponibilidad y valor por esos dias. Gracias

---

Como notaran, los dos campos de fechas estan vacios. Estimo que debo estar cargando mal la variable de cada uno de ellos.
El formulario esta probado y asi como el envío, funcionan muy bien, solo que no se imprimen ambas fechas, acepto vuestras sugerencias, adjunto el codigo del procedimiento,

```
    <!-- WATSAPP -->

    <div class="container">

        <!-- FORMULARIO DE WHATSAPP -->

        <form class="form-wa" action="" id="form">
            <p>Consulta de alquiler por esta propiedad</p>
            <label for="">Nombre:</label>
            <input class="input-Wa" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" >
            <label for="">Cantidad de personas:</label>
            <input class="input-Wa" id="cper" type="text" placeholder="ingrese cuantas personas son para alojarse">
            <label for="">Desde:</label>
            <input class="input-Wa" id="desdeWa" type="date" placeholder="desde"><br>
            <label for="">Hasta:</label>
            <input class="input-Wa" id="hastaWa" type="date" placeholder="hasta" ><br>
            <label for="">Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea class="textarea-Wa" id="txtmensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button class="btn-Wa" id="sendbtn" type="button">Enviar mensaje</button>
        </form>

        <!-- FIN FORMULARIO DE WHATSAPP -->
        
        <!-- Icono de WhatsApp -->

        <img class="icon-wa" src="<?php echo RUTA; ?>assets/img/logo-wa.png" alt="WhatsApp" id="waicon">

    </div>

    <?php $propi = $prop['nombre']; ?> 

    <script>

        var telwa   = "<?php echo $telwa; ?>";
        var prop    = "<?php echo $propi; ?>";          
        var btnwa   = document.querySelector('#waicon');
        var form    = document.querySelector('#form');
        var sendbtn = document.querySelector('#sendbtn');

        btnwa.addEventListener('click', function(){
            form.classList.toggle('entrarysalir')
        })

        sendbtn.addEventListener('click', enviarMensaje)



        function enviarMensaje(){

            var iName    = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var iCper    = document.getElementById('cper').value;
            var iDesde   = document.getElementById('desdeWa').value;
            var iHasta   = document.getElementById('hastaWa').value;
            var iMensaje = document.getElementById('txtmensaje').value;

            var url = 
            "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=549" + telwa + "&text=Hola!,%20Consulta%20desde%20El Sitio Web%0A%0A- Mi nombre:%20" + iName + "%0A- Propiedad:%20" + prop + "%0A- Desde:%20" + iDesde + "%0A- Hasta:%20" + iHasta + "%0A- Para:%20" + iCper + "%20personas.%0A%0A" + "%20- Mensaje:%20" + iMensaje + "%0A";

            /*window.open(encodeURIComponent(url));*/
            window.open(url);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que estás obteniendo?

Comment: Alexis88 Ahi edite la consulta para que sea mas clara con el ejemplo de lo que se carga y lo que se obtiene

Comment: He probado tu código y sí imprime las fechas. Prueba codificando la URL con la función `encodeURIComponent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: No soy tan experto para comprender lo que me estas indicando, ¿como seria la sintaxis?

Comment: Me refiero a esto:  `window.open(encodeURIComponent(url)); `

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente mensaje el navegador:
------------------
Not Found
The requested URL /sitioweb/Alquileres/https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5492983 412679&text=Hola!,%20Consulta%20desde%20El Sitio Web%0A%0A- Mi nombre:%20Ricardo%0A- Propiedad:%20Paumar 1%0A- Desde:%20%0A- Hasta:%20%0A- Para:%204%20personas.%0A%0A%20- Mensaje:%20Consulta por disponibilidad y valores. Gracias%0A was not found on this server.
----------------------

Estimo que sera porque estoy trabajando en el LocalHost

Comment: puedes poner `alert(url);` en la linea siguiente de tu `var url` antes del `window.open(url);` quisiera ver que resultado te vota y tambien en tu button utiliza esto `<button class="btn-Wa" id="sendbtn" type="button">Enviar mensaje</button>`.

Comment: Al probar tu código todo funciona como se espera: https://jsfiddle.net/b26zcqyv/1/ ¿Estás seguro de que es así como lo muestras?

Comment: Totalmente seguro... aqui esta el mensaje del Alert():
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5492983 412679&text=Hola!,%20Consulta%20desde%20El Sitio Web%0A%0A- Mi nombre:%20Ricardo%0A- Propiedad:%20Jardin del Mar%0A- Desde:%20%0A- Hasta:%20%0A- Para:%204%20personas.%0A%0A%20- Mensaje:%20Consulta por esta unidad%0A
y en el formulario cargue 15/01/2022 y 30/01/2022

Comment: Solo he obtenido el mismo resultado que tú si no elijo las fechas. ¿Podrías subir tu proyecto a un servidor para poder probarlo *online*?

Comment: Señores... esta resuelto... resulta que en el codigo php tambien tenia un formulario para enviar email... con los mismos nombres de campos!!! y como el script tomaba esos campos vacios. Muchas gracias... Modifico el codigo para el que lo desee utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Como la fecha viene en formato `AAAA-mm-dd`, solo tienes que:

1. Generar un arreglo separando la cadena a partir de los guiones: `array = fecha.split("-");`
2. Revertir el orden del arreglo resultante: `array.reverse();`
3. Unir los elementos con un `/`: `array.join("/");`

También puedes imprimir todo junto:

```
fecha.split("-").reverse().join("/");
```